# Where can I get a signed iOS 8.2 .ipsw file for iPhone 4S?

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

Until about a week ago, Apple offered a signed version of iOS 8.2. Now the file is not signed anymore. Is there any place where I can still download the signed version of the file? Does anyone still have a copy?

Background: I'm writing an iOS app that I'd like to test on my iPhone, but my version of Xcode can't handle iOS 8.3. As far as I can tell, there are only two ways of making Xcode compatible with my phone: either upgrade OS X to Yosemite or downgrade iOS to 8.2. I'd rather downgrade the phone, I only use it for testing anyway.

Links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Version_comparison_table
https://ipsw.me/iPhone4,1

(Or did I misunderstand the signing process? Maybe the file hasn't changed, and the signing somehow happens during installation?)

**UPDATE**: Yes, I did misunderstand the signing process - during installation, an Apple server has to approve the file for the phone. :-(

But I found another way to make Xcode on Mavericks talk to my iOS 8.3 phone: I downloaded Xcode 6.3 from developer.apple.com, installed it to `/Applications/Xcode-6.3.app`, and copied `/Applications/Xcode-6.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform` to `/Applications/Xcode-6.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform`. Started Xcode 6.2, and could run and debug apps on my phone from Xcode. Also works for Xcode 5.0. More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556950/iphone-running-ios-8-3-shows-up-as-ineligible-in-xcode-6-2-any-solution/29727982#29727982

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple stops signing the old OS within a week or so of a new one coming out, for all devices that can support that OS.

After that, there's no way to go back, unless you saved your [SHSH blob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHSH_blob) from the prior version's installation.

You should be able to get Xcode 6.3.1 from [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) or update from the App Store.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Two remarks: 1. As I said, Xcode 6.3.1 requires OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), and I'd rather not upgrade my Mac yet. 2. If I understand correctly, saving SHSH blobs doesn't help anymore. There is no way to downgrade a 8.3 iPhone. There aren't even jailbreaks. More details here: https://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/APTicket https://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/SHSH